# How replace replace all specific characters using PHP ereg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, replace, ereg-replace

I want replace specific symbols with sign % using regular expressions on PHP. E.g.

```
$result = ereg_replace('xlp','%','example')`. //$result = `'e%a%%me'
```

It is possible or I should use other way?

Comment: Warning ereg_replace() function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, about [`ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php):

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged.

Use `preg_replace` instead.

Next, in your pattern, you are searching for the literal string `xlp`. Put them in a character-set to match **one of** the three.

```
$result = preg_replace(
    "/[xlp]/",
    "%",
    $string
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace` is good, but let's not forget about `str_replace`

```
print str_replace(array('x','l','p'),array('%','%','%'),'example');
// or
print str_replace(array('x','l','p'),'%','example');

//will output
e%am%%e
```

Comment: I think you can use a single `"%"` instead of the replacement array.